# Can I have a series of if/else if statements inside one OnCollisionEnter2D function?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, pong

I'm currently creating a pong game in which the moment the ball hits one of the pong paddles, it splits in two. I do this by destroying the paddle that receives the collision, and instating a split paddle that I've made a prefab.

My issue is every prefab is tagged differently and every time the ball hits a paddle, it should detct that tag and do something... but after the first split, once the new paddle is instantiated, the function doesn't fire...

Can I have several if/else if statements like this? What am I missing?

Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PaddleSplit_Script : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject split_paddle1;
    public GameObject split_paddle2;
    public GameObject split_paddle3;

    public GameObject split_opponent_paddle1;
    public GameObject split_opponent_paddle2;
    public GameObject split_opponent_paddle3;
    //public override void Apply(GameObject target)
    //{
    //    void 

    //    if (target.gameObject.CompareTag("Player 1"))
    //    {

    //        //Instantiate()
    //    }
    //}

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        // Pre-State
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Player 1"))
        {
            Debug.Log("Player Split");
            Destroy(collision.gameObject);
            Instantiate(split_paddle1);
            //Destroy(gameObject);

        }

        else if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Player 2"))
        {
            Debug.Log("Opponent Split");
            Destroy(collision.gameObject);
            Instantiate(split_opponent_paddle1);
            //Destroy(gameObject);
        }

        // Primary State

        else if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Player 1_1"))
        {
            Debug.Log("Player split again");
            Destroy(collision.gameObject);
            Instantiate(split_paddle2);
        }

        else if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Player 2_1"))
        {
            Debug.Log("Opponent split again");
            Destroy(collision.gameObject);
            Instantiate(split_opponent_paddle2);
        }


        // Secondary State

        // else if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Player 1_2"))
        // {
        //     Destroy(collision.gameObject);
        //     Instantiate(split_paddle3);
        // }

        // else if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Player 2_2"))
        // {
        //     Destroy(collision.gameObject);
        //     Instantiate(split_opponent_paddle3);
        // }
    }
}
```

As you'll notice, I broke them down in states (pre-state being the paddle un-split).

What I am trying to accomplish is once the ball hits a paddle, it should detect that collision based off the tag it hits....

Comment: What make you think that multiple `if` statements is the problem? Did you try to remove all but one and confirm that code works as you expect (I don't expect such change will fix what I think the actual problem you have "once the new paddle is instantiated, the function doesn't fire"). Please re-read the [mre] guidance and [edit] post to remove unnecessary code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I have several if/else if statements like this?

Of course you can! `OnCollisionEnter2D` (in this regard) is a `c#` method like any other.

**Should you?** That's another question.

Unfortunately the tag system is quite limited there and not really dynamically extendable. Also you might just miss to tag and referene your objects correctly.

Instead of using `tags` in this case I would rather go with a simple component like e.g.

```
public enum Side
{
    Player,
    Opponent
}

public class Paddle : Monobehaviour
{
    public int splitLevel;
    public Side side;
}
```

and do e.g.

```
public Paddle[] paddlesPrefabs;

private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.TryGetComponent<Paddle>(out var paddle))
    {
        var currentSplitLevel = paddle.splitLevel;
        var side = paddle.Side;

        var newSplitLevel = currentSplitLevel + 1;

        if(newSplitLevel >= paddlesPrefabs.Length)
        {
            // GameOverAndLoserIs(side);
        }
        else
        {
            var newPrefab = paddlesPrefabs[newSplitLevel];
            var newPaddle = Instantiate(newPrefab);
            newPaddle.splitLevel = newSplitLevel;
            newPaddle.side = side;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is a really interesting approach... I'll definitely consider it, thanks again!